# What's the physical or mathematical meaning of considering non-minimal coupling?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, gauge-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Why we still consider the case of non-minimal coupling? And I don't really understand the motivation of coupling.
 In general relativity, the non-minimal coupling violates the principle of equivalence. In gauge field, the minimal coupling represents the covariant derivative of fiber bundles and is consistent with gauge redundancy.
So it seems that there is no reason for us to consider the non-minimal coupling, except the conformal coupling. So why are there so many models of non-minimal coupling?

Comment: What do you mean *"There's no reason for us to consider the non-minimal coupling"*? If the non-minimally coupled Lagrangian is invariant under all relevant symmetry groups, **it is a valid Lagrangian**! Just because it isn't mathematically beautiful, we should not flat out refuse to look at it.

Comment: As an example of why they are interesting, isn't there some result that a small extra dimension produces a dilation which is equivalent (up to changing coordinates) to adding in a coupling to R?

Comment: @ACuriousMind For example in GR, if Ricci scalar couples to a scalar, then principle of equivalence is violated although it's still covariant.

Comment: @jwimberley Thanks! Can you recommend some reference?

Comment: There are many reasons as why should consider non-minimal coupling. they are discussed in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0002091v2.pdf)